# Group By and SUM column

Tags: python, dataframe

I am looking at US census data:

```
                                                population  
State           County    
Alabama         Jefferson County                658466  
                Mobile County                   412992  
                Madison County                  334811  
Alaska          Anchorage Municipality          291826  
                Fairbanks North Star Borough    97581  
                Matanuska-Susitna Borough       88995
```

Final output should sum up the population for each state:

```
State           SumOfPopulation 
Alabama         1406269                  
Alaska          478402
```

My attempts with groupby yielded in below error

```
df.groupby('State')['population'].agg('sum') 

KeyError: 'STNAME'
```

What the appropriate approach would look like?

Comment: `df.groupby('State').sum('population')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code working in [pandas 0.20.0+](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-enhancements), but better is omit `agg` and use `sum` only:

```
df.groupby('State', as_index=False)['population'].sum()
```

But for lower versions first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for columns from `MultiIndex`:

```
df.reset_index().groupby('State', as_index=False)['population'].sum()
```

The simpliest solution is use `sum`:

```
df = df['population'].sum(level='State').reset_index()
#for seelct level by position
#df = df['population'].sum(level=0).reset_index()

print (df)
     State  population
0  Alabama     1406269
1   Alaska      478402
```

Comment: the second statement has worked. Any idea why the first statement still yielded 

     KeyError: 'State' although as_index set to False

Comment: I think because your pandas version is bellow `0.20.0`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('State', as_index=False)['population'].sum()
```

this will work fine

Comment: Please put more description to your answer, otherwise the answer will landing in the Low Quality Posts and It will be removed. I will give you +1.